# Ray-box Intersection Theory

Tags: algorithm, 3d, intersection, raytracing

I wish to determine the intersection point between a ray and a box. The box is defined by its min 3D coordinate and max 3D coordinate and the ray is defined by its origin and the direction to which it points.

Currently, I am forming a plane for each face of the box and I'm intersecting the ray with the plane. If the ray intersects the plane, then I check whether or not the intersection point is actually on the surface of the box. If so, I check whether it is the closest intersection for this ray and I return the closest intersection.

The way I check whether the plane-intersection point is on the box surface itself is through a function

```
bool PointOnBoxFace(R3Point point, R3Point corner1, R3Point corner2)
{
  double min_x = min(corner1.X(), corner2.X());
  double max_x = max(corner1.X(), corner2.X());
  double min_y = min(corner1.Y(), corner2.Y());
  double max_y = max(corner1.Y(), corner2.Y());
  double min_z = min(corner1.Z(), corner2.Z());
  double max_z = max(corner1.Z(), corner2.Z());
  if(point.X() >= min_x && point.X() <= max_x && 
     point.Y() >= min_y && point.Y() <= max_y &&
     point.Z() >= min_z && point.Z() <= max_z)
     return true;

  return false;
}
```

where `corner1` is one corner of the rectangle for that box face and `corner2` is the opposite corner. My implementation works most of the time but sometimes it gives me the wrong intersection. Please see image:

[image]

The image shows rays coming from the camera's eye and hitting the box surface. The other rays are the normals to the box surface. It can be seen that the one ray in particular (it's actually the normal that is seen) comes out from the "back" of the box, whereas the normal should be coming up from the top of the box. This seems to be strange since there are multiple other rays that hit the top of the box correctly.

I was wondering if the way I'm checking whether the intersection point is on the box is correct or if I should use some other algorithm.

Thanks.

Comment: Great diagram.  That really helps illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Increasing things by epsilon is not actually a great way to do this, as you now have a border of size epsilon at the edge of your box through which rays can pass.  So you'll get rid of this (relatively common) weird set of errors, and end up with another (rarer) set of weird errors.

I assume that you're already envisioning that your ray is traveling at some speed along its vector and find the time of intersection with each plane.  So, for example, if you are intersecting the plane at `x=x0`, and your ray is going in direction `(rx,ry,rz)` from `(0,0,0)`, then the time of intersection is `t = x0/rx`.  If `t` is negative, ignore it--you're going the other way.  If `t` is zero, you have to decide how to handle that special case--if you're in a plane already, do you bounce off it, or pass through it?  You may also want to handle `rx==0` as a special case (so that you can hit the edge of the box).

Anyway, now you have exactly the coordinates where you struck that plane: they are `(t*rx , t*ry , t*rz)`.  Now you can just read off whether `t*ry` and `t*rz` are within the rectangle they need to be in (i.e. between the min and max for the cube along those axes).  *You don't test the x coordinate because you already know that you hit it*  Again, you have to decide whether/how to handle hitting corners as a special case.  Furthermore, now you can order your collisions with the various surfaces by time and pick the first one as your collision point.

This allows you to compute, without resorting to arbitrary epsilon-factors, whether and where your ray intersects your cube, to the accuracy possible with floating point arithmetic.

So you just need three functions like the one you've already got: one for testing whether you hit within `yz` assuming you hit `x`, and the corresponding ones for `xz` and `xy` assuming that you hit `y` and `z` respectively.

---

Edit: code added to (verbosely) show how to do the tests differently for each axis:

```
#define X_FACE 0
#define Y_FACE 1
#define Z_FACE 2
#define MAX_FACE 4

// true if we hit a box face, false otherwise
bool hit_face(double uhit,double vhit,
                 double umin,double umax,double vmin,double vmax)
{
  return (umin <= uhit && uhit <= umax && vmin <= vhit && vhit <= vmax);
}

// 0.0 if we missed, the time of impact otherwise
double hit_box(double rx,double ry, double rz,
                double min_x,double min_y,double min_z,
                double max_x,double max_y,double max_z)
{
  double times[6];
  bool hits[6];
  int faces[6];
  double t;
  if (rx==0) { times[0] = times[1] = 0.0; }
  else {
    t = min_x/rx;
    times[0] = t; faces[0] = X_FACE; 
    hits[0] = hit_box(t*ry , t*rz , min_y , max_y , min_z , max_z);
    t = max_x/rx;
    times[1] = t; faces[1] = X_FACE + MAX_FACE;
    hits[1] = hit_box(t*ry , t*rz , min_y , max_y , min_z , max_z);
  }
  if (ry==0) { times[2] = times[3] = 0.0; }
  else {
    t = min_y/ry;
    times[2] = t; faces[2] = Y_FACE;
    hits[2] = hit_box(t*rx , t*rz , min_x , max_x , min_z , max_z);
    t = max_y/ry;
    times[3] = t; faces[3] = Y_FACE + MAX_FACE;
    hits[3] = hit_box(t*rx , t*rz , min_x , max_x , min_z , max_z);
  }
  if (rz==0) { times[4] = times[5] = 0.0; }
  else {
    t = min_z/rz;
    times[4] = t; faces[4] = Z_FACE;
    hits[4] = hit_box(t*rx , t*ry , min_x , max_x , min_y , max_y);
    t = max_z/rz;
    times[5] = t; faces[5] = Z_FACE + MAX_FACE;
    hits[5] = hit_box(t*rx , t*ry , min_x , max_x , min_y , max_y);
  }
  int first = 6;
  t = 0.0;
  for (int i=0 ; i<6 ; i++) {
    if (times[i] > 0.0 && (times[i]<t || t==0.0)) {
      first = i;
      t = times[i];
    }
  }
  if (first>5) return 0.0;  // Found nothing
  else return times[first];  // Probably want hits[first] and faces[first] also....
}
```

(I just typed this, didn't compile it, so beware of bugs.)
(Edit: just corrected an `i` -> `first`.)

Anyway, the point is that you treat the three directions separately, and test to see whether the impact has occurred within the right box in (u,v) coordinates, where (u,v) are either (x,y), (x,z), or (y,z) depending on which plane you hit.

Comment: thank you for the detailed response. I too would prefer to use a method that doesn't rely on an incrementation by epsilon. However, with your method, I must know which axis does the face plane not include, no? If so, how exactly would I check which axis I hit (i.e. can you explain your phrasing in the very last sentence?)

Comment: I've added code to hopefully make that clear.  The key thing to note is that you do different `hit_box` tests depending on which face you're testing.  (For example, the first one tested is `min_x` and we see whether the impact point is within the `yz` rectangle.)

Comment: thank you for the code. It made things clearer for me. In your code, you make checks like `if(rx==0)...if(ry==0)...if(rz==0)`. Is this true for an "axis-aligned box"? I'm just worried that the box may be oriented in such a way that its planes may not necessarily lie along the x,y, or z axis.

Comment: That is to handle the case where the ray is parallel to one of the faces--otherwise I'd divide by zero.  In that case, I say that it always misses the face using the logic above.  If your box is _not_ aligned along the axes, rotate the coordinates of the _vector_ (and origin) so that it is, then do your comparisons--this way you can use exact tests as shown here.

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanations. Greatly appreciate it! =)

Answer (score 2):

`PointOnBoxFace` should be a two-dimensional check instead of three-dimensional.  For example, if you're testing against the `z = z_min` plane, then you should only need to compare `x` and `y` to their respective boundaries.  You've already figured out that `z` coordinate is correct.  Floating point precision is likely tripping you up as you "re-check" the third coordinate.

For example, if `z_min` is 1.0, you first test against that plane.  You find an intersection point of (`x`, `y`, 0.999999999).  Now, even though `x` and `y` are within bounds, the `z` isn't quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine. Try to find this particular ray and debug it.

Comment: is there a different way I can check whether or not a particular point is on the surface of the box? Perhaps using rays and 3D point as opposed to checking the x,y,z coordinates explicitly?

Comment: you can and you should. treat ray as vector and find x,y, z of intersection by equation

Comment: I have found the x,y,z of the intersection by equation. The goal now is to find whether this x,y,z is on a certain face of the box and I was wondering if there's an equation for that

Comment: Code doesn't look fine.  It tests something Myx is already assuming, namely that one face has been hit.  Testing _again_ is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ignore this answer (see comments below where I am quite convincingly shown the error of my ways).

You are testing whether the point is inside the volume, but the point is on the periphery of that volume, so you may find that it is an "infinitesimal" distance outside the volume. Try growing the box by some small epsilon, e.g.:

```
double epsilon = 1e-10; // Depends the scale of things in your code.
double min_x = min(corner1.X(), corner2.X()) - epsilon;
double max_x = max(corner1.X(), corner2.X()) + epsilon;
double min_y = min(corner1.Y(), corner2.Y()) - epsilon;
...
```

Technically, the correct way to compare almost-equal numbers is to cast their bit representations to ints and compare the integers for some small offset, e.g., in C:

```
#define EPSILON 10 /* some small int; tune to suit */
int almostequal(double a, double b) {
    return llabs(*(long long*)&a - *(long long*)&b) < EPSILON;
}
```

Of course, this isn't so easy in C#, but perhaps unsafe semantics can achieve the same effect. (Thanks to @Novox for his comments, which lead me to a nice [page](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm) explaining this technique in detail.)

Comment: seems like this did the fix for the example I have shown above. Thank you! However, I feel a little uncomfortable making such a change. Would you by any chance have another, perhaps more geometrically related, fix?

Comment: Be aware however not to choose an epsilon that's *too* small; else your FPUs end up messing with denorms (i.e. not normalized floating point numbers) which can hurt performance quite severly.

Comment: @Myx, this is a fundamental property of floating point computation. The problem is that rounding errors have crept in to your point calculation and produced a tiny offset. Perhaps you arrange to snap the point to the surface it matched against (e.g., if it matches an x-y face, set the point's z to the z of the surface).

Comment: +1 @Novox. Thanks for pointing that out. I should say, however, that picking a denorm for your epsilon will probably defeat the technique, since adding a denorm to a normal number (within a few orders of magnitude of 1) will have no effect.

Comment: @Novox and @Marcelo: can you explain the idea behind denorms? I've never heard of those before up until now...

Comment: This is a good answer for some problems, but not for Myx' problem.  Now you hit things you shouldn't that have barely missed--and you do so unnecessarily.

Comment: @Myx: Floating points are represented using a binary mantissa mmmm and exponent eee, that together represent the number 1.mmmm*2^eee. When the number gets too close to zero, eee reaches its negative limit, and the number is now represented as, say, 0.01mm*2^eee. This is a denormalised float. The problem with these numbers is lost precision and more work for the FPU.

Comment: This is a hack that simply postpones the problem.

Comment: @Adrian, epsilon comparisons are a well-known mechanism for dealing with rounding errors in floating point code (especially if you use the int-casting method). They are also more general than your solution, which can only deal with axis-aligned rectangular cuboids.

Comment: @Marcelo: epsilon comparisons are great for some problems but _not this problem_.  It _is_ a rectangular cuboid, and anyway, it's a _volume collision test_ where you never need to epsilonize when you hit flat surfaces (unless your volumes are less than epsilon thick).  This is a good approach for polyhedral surface reflections.

Comment: @Marcelo: epsilon adjustments are fine for some types of rounding errors, but not this one.  My solution generalizes: you project the 3D collision candidate to the plane containing the polygon and then do a 2D check.  The fact that the posted question is about an axis aligned rectangular prism makes that trivial.

Comment: @Marcelo: Epsilon comparisons are appropriate for some problems, but not for this one. The code has already ensured that one dimension is met and reduced the problem to 2D. Re-checking that dimension with looser constraints is a waste. Once you find that the ray hits the plane, you project the hit point and the polygon (rectangle in this case) to an appropriate plane and do a simple 2D check--no fudging needed. Since the original post used an access-aligned box, dropping the dimension that's already been checked is an easy way to do the projection.  [reposting because SO lost my last comment]

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that that ray ends up passing exactly through the edge of the box? Floating point roundoff errors might cause it to be missed by both the right and the back face.

Comment: from the visual feedback, doesn't seem that this is the case. But this is something that I should probably handle as well (I wasn't going to worry about it until later). How could I go about fixing this problem? (i.e. if the ray hits exactly on the edge or at the corner)